# Can Raspbmc generate events for other event servers?

Tags: gpio, hardware, raspbmc

I would like to use the raspberry pi to switch off my Power amplifier once I am done playing a movie. I also want to use it to start the Power Amplifier at a specific time as an alarm.

If I write a server to control IO pins, can I get raspbmc to inform the sever of what is going on? Or is polling raspbmc the only option?

Comment: Slightly off topic. Couldn't you use IR to turn the amp on/off? Support for LIRC is pretty good for the Pi. Just add an IR-led to one of the pins (with resistor), and your done.

Comment: The Power Amplifier is external. I have to get PI control a relay to switch it off and on.

Comment: No :-( Unfortunately not.